# Leading spaces were removed but RegEx brought back the initial issue

Tags: regex

[image: snapshot2]

What I want:

1. dot in front of numerator need to be removed
2. there should not be any leading spaces
3. output should have both decimal and float numbers

Expressions used so far, but didn't work:

#### Attempt 1

```
twt_clean.text.str.extract('((.(?=\d+)[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/([1-9][0-9]+))')
```

This introduced leading spaces in front of float numbers

#### Attempt 2

```
twt_clean.text.str.extract('((?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/[1-9][0-9]+)')
```

This brought back the initial issue(dot in front) for which this extract step was written.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide sample input & output?

Comment: Does `([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/([1-9][0-9]+)` work?

Comment: Yes it did. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+)/([1-9]\d+)
```

I dropped the most external pair of parentheses, so it contains only:

- `(...)` - the numerator part (capturing groupt No 1).
- `/` - represents itself.
- `([1-9]\d+)` - denominator part (capturing groupt No 2).

Description concerning the numerator part:

- `\d+\.\d+` - The first alternative: a sequence of digits, a dot
  and another sequence of digits (the decimal variant).
- `|` - Alternative separator.
- `\d+` - The second alternative: a sequence of digits (the integer variant).

This way, any initial spaces and **initial** dot are not captured.

For a working example (Python regex flavour) see https://regex101.com/r/ib7UsW/1

As you can see in the source part of the above example,
each source row contains a leading space and one of them contains also an
initial dot. All of them are **not** captured.